# How to obtain the JSON data from byte array class?

Tags: json, python-3.x

After decompressing the compressed value using https://pypi.org/project/lz4/
, I got the following data:

b'\x81\xa2kn\xdc\x00\x15\xb30.02223516846295757\xa42.29\xa3752\xa210\xc0\xc0\xc0\xc0\xc0\xc0\xc0\xa31.5\xa15\xa30.3\xa11\xa30.6\xa12\xc0\xc0\xa41146\xa820180725'

The type of above data is: class 'bytes'

The data is actually JSON data with key-value pair type of information. How should I proceed further to convert the above data to JSON in Python?

Comment: You'll first have to find out which encoding this bytestring is since it's neither utf-8 nor latin-1. Are you sure it has been correctly decompressed ?

Comment: Most probably the decompressing is happening fine. I tried x.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'). But then the obtained string is not properly in key- value pair

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers after investigating I found it was encoded  with base64 encoding too in java. But now have to be decoded in python

Comment: I'm afraid there's still something wrong - applying `b64.b64decode()` to your bytestring raises `binascii.Error: Incorrect padding`. Actually your real problem is not "How to obtain the JSON data" but "How to get the proper bytestring out of whereever you got this from", and no one can help you with this - at least not without knowing where those data come from etc. Once you get this problem solved, it's just a matter of decoding the bytestring to a unicode string (which requires knowing the character encoding used for the bytestring) and passing it to `json.loads()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your byte data doesn't look like a proper string.
Usually you should be able to convert it to string using `x.decode('utf-8')` and then string to JSON using `json.loads(json_string)` or any other way you prefer.

Idea is

- Convert bytes to string
- Convert string to JSON.

Comment: You don't "convert a string to JSON" - json is a text format, not a data type. What `json.loads()` do is _parse_ a string in json format and return the corresponding Python data structure - either a dict (most often) or list.